# Why is for loop modifying an additional variable not referenced in the line (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I set two global variables:

```
var topList = {
    a: {},
    b: {},
    c: {},
    d: {},
    e: {}
}

var compare = {
    a: {},
    b: {},
    c: {},
    d: {},
    e: {}
}
```

I have a function which populates each of them, and then uses a for loop to swap out the `a` object within the `compare` variable. Then it calls a function to compare the new `compare` to `topList`, and returns the better of the two (thus setting `topList` as the better of the two:

```
function optimize(data){

    var rawList = data.slice();

    var aList = $.grep(rawList, function(e) { return e.position == "A" });
    var bList = $.grep(rawList, function(e) { return e.position == "B" });
    var cList = $.grep(rawList, function(e) { return e.position == "C" });
    var dList = $.grep(rawList, function(e) { return e.position == "D" });
    var eList = $.grep(rawList, function(e) { return e.position == "E" });

    topList.a = aList[0];
    topList.b = bList[0];
    topList.c = cList[0];
    topList.d = dList[0];
    topList.e = eList[0];

    compare = topList;

    for (i = 0, len = aList.length; i < len; i++) {
        compare.a = aList[i];
        topList = best(topList, compare);
    }
}
```

For some reason, it seems that when the line `compare.a = aList[i];` is executed, it's not only swapping out the `a` object in the `compare` variable, but also the `a` object in the `topList` variable. As a result I'm always sending two identical lists through my "best" function, which makes it useless.

I'm new to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is `$.grep` doing?

Comment: is `compare` a reference to `topList`? e.g. does `compare === topList` evaluate to `true` when you run it in the developer console?

Comment: If this is jQuery please tag as such.

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm using $.grep to filter an array. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an attempt to explain simply, when you do:

```
var x = {};
```

You take an empty object and assign it to `x`.

If you then do:

```
var y = x;
```

You are taking the *same object* and assigning it to `y` as well.

From then, if you do...

```
y.foo = 'bar';
```

You will find that...

```
alert(x.foo); // bar (!)
```

This is called assignment by-reference, and it is what happens in JavaScript with objects (note that arrays are objects too, with predefined methods).

The opposite is assignment by-value, where the value is copied to the new variable.

So because you have this by-reference assignment, changes you make in one place will affect the other. You will need to use a copying function to get a new object, unrelated to the first, with the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Because compare is a reference to topList.
You don't need to put

```
compare =topList;
```

Simply, this would work :

```
compare .a = aList[0];
compare .b = bList[0];
compare .c = cList[0];
compare .d = dList[0];
compare .e = eList[0];
```